# Grouping strings based on two keys

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings with each string having two digits separated by `#`.

I want to group strings such that `1#2` and `2#1` would be in the same group..

For example,take this list as an example

```
{"1#2","1#6","1#2","2#1"}
```

I want to group this list in this way

```
key=1#2 or 2#1
Value={"1#2","1#2","2#1"}

key=1#6 or 6#1
Value={"1#6"}
```

So I want to group strings based on two different keys.

I tried

```
list.GroupBy(x=>x);
```

But it groups it into three keys `1#2`,`2#1`,`1#6` instead of two keys `1#2 or 2#1`,`1#6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new string[] {"1#2","1#2","2#1"};
    var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Split('#').OrderBy(y => y).Aggregate((a,b)=>a + "#" + b));

    //should output only one key - 1#2
    foreach(var key in result)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
}
```

It should work even if there are more than 2 values, etc 1#2#3

Comment: Very nice trick..Worked for me with `String.Join("",x.Split('#').OrderBy(y => y))` ..Thank you..

Comment: Nice to hear. I just want to point out that you should use some kind of separater for `string.Join` otherwise you could run in problems with values like `1#120` and `11#20`. They will have the same key `1120` with your code.